# Bad Request when sending POST /messages to Let's Chat API

Tags: curl, letschat

I am trying to create a bash/curl script that sends a message to a [Let's Chat](https://sdelements.github.io/lets-chat/) server.

[The API](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/wiki/API%3A-Messages) works fine for reading messages:

```
$ curl --user `cat token.txt`:abc \  
    http://192.168.0.1:5000/rooms/slugsample/messages
[{"id":"559cf90802b85abb776a307b","text":"Salut [...]
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to work to send a new message:

```
$ curl --data '{"text":"Hello"}' --user `cat token.txt`:abc \  
    http://192.168.0.1:5000/rooms/slugsample/messages
Bad Request
```

What am I doing wrong?

*curl 7.38.0*
*Let's Chat 0.4.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to specify that the content type is JSON. Curl allows you to add header information with the `-H` option.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"text":"Hello"}' \
http://192.168.0.1:5000/rooms/slugsample/messages --user `cat          \
token.txt`:username
```

*Edit*

I spinned up a Let's Chat Docker container and confirmed that the above curl works.

I also got a `HTTP Error - 400 Bad Request` when I did NOT include the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`